# ASP.NET fade textbox text when user clicks

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, fade

I'm developing an ASP.NET (VS2012, .NET 4) web app, and I'm going to create some effects for my text box like this site:

http://behnoush.iitco.ir/site/fa/Poll.html

as you can see, when user clicks on text boxes, their text is faded to a lighter color, also there is a picture in the textbox, I have found this site:
http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/
which is a jquery for simulating color fade effect, but in fact it uses labels, is there any way I can perform these nice effects with jquery and TEXTBOX? I've tested some methods for changing textbox text color when it receives focus, but there was no luck! also how can I display similar icons in my textboxes?

thanks

Comment: Can you post? what have you tested so far.

Comment: I've tested juqery animate (color), but with no luck!

Comment: The site you reference is animating `opacity` to get the fade effect.

Comment: well thanks but how can I change opacity? Jquery? how can I insert image in my textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want for webkit browsers. just adjust color as desired.

```
     ::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #808080; }         
     :focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #d0d0d0;  transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
```